# Recreate a Session by Using Your Session ID In ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, sessionid

I would like to know if ASP.NET has something similar to `session_id` function from PHP.

I would like to do something like it using ASP.NET:

```
session_id($_GET['session_name']);
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['mydata'] != 'somepreviousvaluesetted') {
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        exit;
}
```

That is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session object has a SessionID property, but it does not give you the ability to start a session; however, in global.asax, there is a Session_Start handler which fires when the session does start.  The session starts when the user accesses the application.

HTH.